# How to use assert in Python production source code?

Tags: python, django, assert

We are looking at self-developed libraries shared between multiple Django projects or components of the same project, not the published open-source libraries.

**Question:**

We wonder whether it is OK to use `assert` to validate the variable's values.

We didn't find online articles in this topic, so if yes, how do we do it?

**More information:**

1. An example of our idea:
   We are considering the example below that verifies the input `logic` equals to either `and` or `or`. And the design seems better than using a `else` clause assuming the value must be the other one.

```py
if logic == 'and':
    main_Q = main_Q & filter_Q
elif logic == 'or':
    main_Q = main_Q | filter_Q
else:
    assert False, "Invalid value of `logic`, it needs to be either `and` or `or`."
```

Or:

```py
if logic == 'and':
    main_Q = main_Q & filter_Q
else:
    assert logic == 'or'
    main_Q = main_Q | filter_Q
```

2. We found usages of `assert` in the published open-source libraries.
   By doing a `grep "assert" -v "test"` to search in the `site-packages` directory, we found multiple `assert` statements in the functional source code, not for testing, in the libraries of `amqp`, `argparse`, `billiard`, `celery`, `dateutil`, `decorator`, `distlib`, etc. However, using assert seems to be an advanced technique, and we need help to find articles about the how-to's.

```
./amqp/sasl.py:        assert isinstance(mechanism, bytes)
./amqp/sasl.py:        assert isinstance(response, bytes)
Binary file ./amqp/__pycache__/sasl.cpython-37.pyc matches
./argparse.py:        assert self._current_indent >= 0, 'Indent decreased below 0.'
./argparse.py:                assert ' '.join(opt_parts) == opt_usage
./argparse.py:                assert ' '.join(pos_parts) == pos_usage
./argparse.py:            assert action_tuples
./arrow-0.17.0.dist-info/LICENSE:      incurred by, or claims asserted against, such Contributor by reason
./attr/_compat.py:            raise AssertionError  # pragma: no cover
./attr/_compat.py:            raise AssertionError  # pragma: no cover
Binary file ./attr/__pycache__/_compat.cpython-37.pyc matches
./billiard/connection.py:                    assert waitres == WAIT_OBJECT_0
./billiard/connection.py:            assert err == 0

... and many more matches ...
```

3. We verified in test that the assertion fails only the one thread fulfilling the incoming HTTP request, and it does not fail the entire Django project. So, there is less worry about over-killing, but we also want to get confirmation from experts.

We highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

Comment: I would not call `assert` an "advanced technique". But, the correct advice is that it you *shouldn't use it for code that you want to always raise an exception*, because depending on how Python is run, assert statements can get removed/ignored during execution. So you should really just change `assert <condition>` to `if <condition>: raise AppropriateException("appropriate error message")`

Comment: `assert False, "Invalid value of \`logic\`, it needs to be either \`and\` or \`or\`."`is absolutely wrong. this should be a `raise`

Answer (score 2):

I've used asserts before while writing production Django code. Here is my advice:

1. **Try to make every assert unreachable**. If you have an assert, and in the operation of your product by a non-programmer, that assert can fail, then that is a bug. (Even if what the user is trying to do *should* be an error, it shouldn't be an assert.)

   The assert may be guarding against undesirable behavior, and be better than having no error handling at all. Even so, it shouldn't be an assert. If you have a reachable assert, then you should replace that with error handling which raises a more specific error, or prevent the assert from being reached somehow.

   Assertion errors should not signify "something went wrong." Assertion errors should signify "something went wrong, in a way the programmers didn't anticipate."

   (One exception to this rule: if you're creating something for programmers, like a library, it's fine to have asserts which are reachable by users of your library. Programmers are expected to be able to read asserts. Be wary of rule #3, though.)
2. **Don't use asserts for validating user input**. This falls out of the previous rule. Imagine you want to prevent a user from using spaces in their username. Don't write

   ```
   assert " " not in username, "No spaces in username"
   ```

   Instead, write code which raises a specific exception:

   ```
   if " " in username:
        raise ValidationError(_("No spaces in username"), code="no-space-username")
   ```

   Django and Django Rest Framework both have ways to map an exception into a specific HTTP status code.
3. **Caught asserts are a code smell**. If you're ever tempted to write...

   ```
   try:
       ...
   except AssertionError:
       ...
   ```

   ... this is a sign you shouldn't be using assert. You should be raising some more specific exception and catching it, so that you don't catch an assert you don't intend.
4. **Look for comments which ought to be asserts**. If you're ever tempted to write a comment to the effect of "x cannot be zero at this point," consider writing an assert instead.

   This is better than a comment, because a comment can become out of date after you refactor code. If an assert's assumption no longer holds, you will immediately notice, because it'll create an error.
5. **Failed asserts should be logged**. Django comes with logging which allows you to log exceptions and send you an email each time it happens. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/logging/). You should use this, or some other error reporting service. (I use [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) for this.)